# In Visual Studio 2010 pressing Alt + Enter should open F# Interactive?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

In Visual Studio 2010 pressing Alt + Enter should open F# Interactive?

I'm selecting F# code, and pressing Alt + Enter, but nothing happens!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keybindings depend on the global environment settings (and you can also change them), but:

- The default keybinding for opening F# interacative (if it is closed) is `Ctrl + Alt + F`. Otherwise, you can find the window in *View -> Other Windows -> F# Interactive*
- Then you should be able to use `Alt + Enter` to interactively execute the selected text.

Comment: ReSharper, in particular, likes to stomp on `Alt + Enter`. I remapped the "send to F# interactive" to `Alt + ;` because I'm used to using the ReSharper key bindings in C# code.

Comment: Thanks @Joel, I;m using your solution.

Answer (score 13):

The command to assign (in Tools-Options-Keyboard) is called

**EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.ExecuteInInteractive**

By default, the hot-key combination, within a TextEditor is Alt+Enter. I like Joel's idea of remapping it (since ReSharper stole that one) to Alt+;.

Comment: i remapped to alt + a random macro key.

Answer (score 1):

No. It copies and executes the selected texts to the interactive window. You need to already have opened the interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

Try the menu: "View\F# Interactive" (if in F# profile) or "View\Other Windows\F# Interactive" (if in a different profile).